# is that Android devices lower then Android 4.3 having bluetooth 4.0 not supporting BLE?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

Actually my laptop with Bluetooth 4.0 is successfully searching and pairing with hardware cc2540 but android phones with bluetooth 4.0 and jelly beans are not able to search cc2540.
I have tried Samsung Galaxy s4 and Samsung Galaxy star and other devices. I will be really thankful if any body can tell me how to connect android Bluetooth 4.0 devices with cc2540.

Comment: Is it somehow related to programming?

Comment: I guess you should ask your question here : http://superuser.com/

Comment: Basically i am working with Bluetooth low energy device. My android phone having Bluetooth 4.0 and jelly beans but it is not able search that smart device. As i here that Android 4.3 Jelly beans is supporting BLE natively. So, i was asking that only Android 4.3 jelly bean devices can connect with smart and smart ready devices ?

Comment: my guess is that even though it is possible, but i don't think google will release a compatibility sdk for this. i wish google would make compatibility sdks for all of the new android OSs features, but they only publish some, and even then they are usually partial and very basic compared to the original ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great i got my answer :) it Only works on 4.3, the earlier API versions do not have Bluetooth Smart API.